# Finding all the combinations of ways to slice the presidential vote

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm a journalist who's trying to scope out how many ways a theoretical presidential vote could be split among *n* candidates.

The vote must add up to 100. Each candidate can score between 0-100.

So if there are three candidates, Candidate A could score 55 and Candidate B could score 20, leaving Candidate C to score 25... and so on.

I'm grasping toward the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58834/number-of-possible-results-in-election-with-one-of-candidates-getting-more-then) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453661/how-many-combinations-of-3-natural-numbers-are-there-that-add-up-to-30?newreg=01d10b32cea64dd68c8b59d9a20b2a41), but I'm afraid I'm a bit out of my depth.

Comment: One can compute this readily using the Stars and Bars method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical terms you ask **how many 3-tuples $\{a,b,c\}$ exist such that $a+b+c = 100$ and $0 \le a,b,c \le 100$?**
Straighforward the answer is
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{100 + 3- 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{102}{2} = \frac{102!}{2!\cdot100!} = \frac{102 \cdot 101}{2} = 5151$$
**Explanation:** you can visualize $n$ bars (the 100 votes) in sequence like
$$* \quad * \quad * \quad * \quad * \quad \ldots \quad *$$
then what you want is the number of ways to divide them into $k$ set. In short your're asking in how many ways you can divide those stars: but that's exactly the *"chose $k-1$ spaces among $n-1$ available"* problem, in other words the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

However your question is slighty different: the candidates can take also $100$ and $0$ values (everybody votes for them, or nobody does), hence the *available* spaces to divide the stars are not only $n-1$ but $n+k-1$ and thus the combinations of nonnegative integer $k-$tuples that sum up to $n$ are $\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 100 balls in a single row. To divide the line of balls into three distinct sets, we can place two divisions in any two spaces available. Notice that there are $100 - 1 = 99$ available slots. For $n$ portions, we place $n - 1$ divisions. Thus, the number of ways is $\boxed{\dbinom{99}{n - 1}}.$